# RailsのViewで条件分岐を見やすくする方法はありますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails4.2を使っています。

なにかの一覧ページで、1件もデータがない場合は「データがありません」という表示にし、データがあればTableを表示させています。コード的には普通に articles.size を見て条件分岐させています。

```
- if articles.size == 0
  | 1件も登録されていません
- else
  table
    tr
      articles.each do |article|
        td = article.title
```

シンプルなHTMLであれば、これで見難いということはないのですが、もう少し大きくなると、見難くなるような気がしています。これを解消する良い方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

partialを使うと解決出来ると思います。
サンプルコード

```
# app/views/hoges/show.html.haml
- if articles.size.zero?
  1件も登録されていません
- else
  render 'table'

# app/views/hoges/_table.html.haml
%table
  %tr
    articles.each do |article|
      %td= article.title
```

ファイル名に関しては適切な名前に置き換えて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりpartialが良さそうですね。
また、articles.size.zero?という表記も忘れていたので参考になりました。

Answer (score 0):

渡しの場合、特に複雑なviewの条件分岐ではhelperと組み合わせることが多いです。

```
# app/helpers/article_helper.rb
def render_article_table(articles)
  if articles.empty?
    "1件も登録されていません"
  elsif articles.present?
    render partial: 'table', locals: { articles: articles }
  else
    render partial: 'hoge', locals: { fuga: fuga }
  end
end

# article.html.slim

= render_article_table(articles)
```